# App crashes on sqlite after updating the app

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, crash

After updating the app, there is a problem with sqlite database. The app crashes. Here ist my log, but I am not sure what can be wrong:

```
Stack: (
"0   MyApp                       0x00085bdb MyApp + 543707",
"1   MyApp                       0x0008633d MyApp + 545597",
"2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3af73e8b _sigtramp + 34",
"3   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3792c447 sqlite3_log + 4986",
"4   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3792c447 sqlite3_log + 4986",
"5   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3791d1cb sqlite3_exec + 11954",
"6   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3791b989 sqlite3_exec + 5744",
"7   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3791b119 sqlite3_exec + 3584",
"8   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3791ac17 sqlite3_exec + 2302",
"9   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3791a977 sqlite3_exec + 1630",
"10  libsqlite3.dylib                    0x3795195f sqlite3_prepare_v2 + 30",
"11  MyApp                       0x00091ca7 MyApp + 593063",
"12  MyApp                       0x00094211 MyApp + 602641",
"13  MyApp                       0x000c09d9 MyApp + 784857",
"14  UIKit                               0x3a044545 <redacted> + 412",
"15  UIKit                               0x3a02930b <redacted> + 1310",
"16  UIKit                               0x3a0407c7 <redacted> + 206",
"17  UIKit                               0x39ffc803 <redacted> + 258",
"18  QuartzCore                          0x3bcd0d63 <redacted> + 214",
"19  QuartzCore                          0x3bcd0901 <redacted> + 460",
"20  QuartzCore                          0x3bcd1835 <redacted> + 16",
"21  QuartzCore                          0x3bcd121b <redacted> + 238",
"22  QuartzCore                          0x3bcd1029 <redacted> + 316",
"23  UIKit                               0x3a1cc1e1 <redacted> + 112",
"24  UIKit                               0x3a07c627 <redacted> + 34",
"25  CoreFoundation                      0x342be6cd <redacted> + 20",
"26  CoreFoundation                      0x342bc9c1 <redacted> + 276",
"27  CoreFoundation                      0x342bcc91 <redacted> + 608",
"28  CoreFoundation                      0x3422febd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356",
"29  CoreFoundation                      0x3422fd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104",
"30  GraphicsServices                    0x377742eb GSEventRunModal + 74",
"31  UIKit                               0x3a04d2f9 UIApplicationMain + 1120",
"32  MyApp                       0x000036e3 MyApp + 9955",
"33  MyApp                       0x0000369c MyApp + 9884"
)
```

Row 11 shows that a problem is with the function sqlite3_prepare_v2 in my function:

```
- (BOOL) checkIfTableExist:(NSString *) tableName
{
BOOL exist = NO;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '%@'", tableName];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        exist = YES;

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}

[sql release];

return exist;
}
```

Could be that after updating the app the database file was broken or something?

Comment: Have you checked after you updating your app, required sqlite file exists or not. You can check the same programmatically or via firefox plugin Sqlite. Possibly, you rebuild your db and that's why your query is not able to execute as no db present. One more-thing from your function it seems that you're going for checking for db exists or not...so for this please google as this is not the right way.

Comment: In the init function of my class I check if the sqlite database file exists. I didn't change the structure or anything with database in the last update. Maybe the file was corrupted? But why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you didn't opened your database. There is no `sqlite3_open` call in your code.

So the database variable will contain a garbage value. That's why it is crashing.

```
- (BOOL) checkIfTableExist:(NSString *) tableName
{
  BOOL exist = NO;
  if (sqlite3_open([yourDatabasePath UTF8String], &dataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '%@'", tableName];
    const char *query = [sql UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    { 
       if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
           exist = YES;

       sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
  }
 return exist;
}
```

Comment: I open the database in the init function of my class. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @bialek: please remove the `[sql release]` and check

Comment: When I test the app, then everything works. Only for some users after updating, the app crashes.